# Delete Partial Row In A Shared Workbook USING VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I delete part of a row within a shared workbook using VBA? The workbook needs to remain Shared.

I have selected my range and I would usually use:

```
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

However,

> this command is not available in a shared workbook

. Any suggestions (without unsharing the workbook!!!)?! Thanks!!

Comment: braX stop editing my post incorrectly, I'm sick of rolling it back.

Comment: You should not include the language tags in the title. That's what the **tags** are for. He's correct in editing that out.

Comment: These questions appear in search engines, the distinction is I want to delete in VBA, not just in general, the question will attract people who won't necessarily be able to help otherwise.  This site has so many petty rules that deter the average user.  I appreciate there needs to be structure, but that rule is ridiculous, it quickly identifies what I want.

Comment: I'm retracting what I said. Found a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316990/the-search-engine-seems-to-encourage-adding-language-tags-to-titles) regarding the same issue.

Comment: Ah good! Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think macro visibility will work for shared workbook approach.

[Program with shared workbook:](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-excel-with/0596007663/ch08s03.html)

> Once you share a workbook, any Visual Basic project it contains is no
>   longer accessible. Excel can't deal with multiple users editing the
>   same macros, so it simply prevents changes to those macros. You can't
>   record new macros, either. However, you can run macros from shared
>   workbooks.

According to this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/6ccb2de2-e080-45e1-a806-f29f2c69916c/common-issues-of-shared-workbook?forum=excel) you cannot delete rows in a shared workbook (Note wasn't tested for 2016)

[image: Shared workbook limitations]

This [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534) recommends [co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) which is the replacement for Shared Workbooks which has limitations. Then use code to delete rows.

Note: That simply unchecking the box, "Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This also allows workbook merging", in  Review   >   Track   Changes   >   Highlight   Changes will unshare the workbook and changes may be lost.

With all that said, with a protected shared workbook on shared drive, using Excel 2016, I and colleagues seem to be able to delete rows in the test case I set up so unsure if there are some settings I have missed or if 2016 is different.